# Переделать секунды в минуты, часы, и дни

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Такой вопрос у меня есть БД в которой есть поле length.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если число в БД будет 1800, то оно конвертируется в 30Мин. Или 3600 То в 1 час.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или вот ещё пример -60 должно отобразится в "Сессия"

Проблема в том, когда я пытаюсь сделать любое действие над Length
Возникает ошибка  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'IntegerField' and 'int'

Так-же это все должно корректно отобразится в шаблоне.

Надеюсь я понятно спросил, всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы не умеете делить на 60?

Comment: А вы не умеете общаться с уважением, не стоит пожалуйста отвечать больше мне. Удачи в ваших проектах.

Comment: Ну просто, если бы вы умели делить на 60, то вы бы знали, что если 1800 секунд поделить на 60 (секунд в минуте), то получится 30 минут.

Comment: @Danber Уважение надо заслужить. Человеку, который не потрудился хоть что-то сделать сам, лучше не выпендриваться. Думаю, ваш вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Начнем с того, что когда ты начинаешь общаться с человеком ты должен его сразу уважать, а потом по мере того, как протекает общение, ты решаешь уважать его или нет. В вопросе я спрашиваю, как мне переконвертировать секунды в минуты. Если вы посмотрите то увидете что поле в котором содержится информация времени(секунды) имеет тип IntegerField(). И если я начну делать это все на 60,  или просто начну делать какие либо действия будет ошибка TypeError. И поэтому я решил спросить у людей которые опытнее меня. Но если человек отвечает "Вы делить на 60 умеете". То с ним не хочется общаться дальше.

Comment: @strawdog надеюсь, теперь вы поняли мою проблему, если нет, спрашивайте, если хотите помочь конечно.

Comment: Я не знаю, откуда у вас такое мировоззрение, но я вас уверяю, вежливость и уважение - разные вещи. Уважение нужно заслужить. Потому что уважают "за что-то". А теперь по существу, добавьте ваш пространный комментарий в части, касающейся проблемы, в тело вопроса.

Comment: Покажите [mcve] с кодом который даёт ошибку

Answer (score 0):

В твоём случае lenght - это не число, а объект "числовое поле", нужно получить из него число соответствующим методом.